# Git hosting using an FTP-accessible web server?

Tags: git, version-control, ftp

I run a (terrible) website that's hosted on a third-party web server. I have FTP access to my web server. Git supposedly has the ability to push/pull via FTP natively.

Since my web server is already accessible everywhere, I was hoping to use it as a centralized Git repository. I could push updates to it, then get them from anywhere.

The problem is that when I try to push to it, I'm getting the following error:

`error: RETR response: 550 while accessing [insert my repository info here]`

550 seems to be an FTP permission denied error. However, I have the correct username and password inserted. I'm able to create whatever folder structure I want through an FTP client, so what special permissions does Git need if I can already read and write as I please?

**EDIT**: I do not not have SSH access to this web server -- only FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git really isn't designed to be used as a central repository like CVS or SubVersion. What you can do is clone your local repository and host it on your server. When you make changes you commit them locally, and when you are ready to update your repository on your server you use a git push command. Here's a link to show you how sourceforge does it. [sourceforge example](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git). Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do -- a `git push` to my FTP. But it doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the number of concurrent FTP connections you are allowed to open? Could you get your hands on the relevant parts of the FTP-Server log?

Comment: @u-punkt That's an interesting idea... I looked through the file system on the other end and didn't see any obvious logs that would store something like that. Not sure if perhaps there's more info available inside git.

Comment: I don't think git will help you here. The 550 response is probably all git gets. FTP server logs will likely have more info. Perhaps you can get in touch with the server admin for help?

Answer (score 1):

how about [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp)? It seems to be the right solution.

Comment: Although I'm long done this project, this does seem like a useful tool! Thanks for mentioning it.