# Git Bash to Create Repository in Network Places?

Tags: git, repository, git-bash

First off, I'm on a Windows XP SP 3 computer. 2nd I know how to use GitBash, but I don't know how to get to my Network Places area within it so that I can create a git repository of a folder within a directory of my FTP Site (which is in Network Places).

Basically, the whole point of me creating the Network in Windows XP was so that I can create a Git Repository within a folder on the Network, however, I thought this would be possible, but maybe now I'm proven wrong in thinking this?

How do I browse to the Network in Network Places that I setup in Windows XP, through GitBash and create a Git Repository in there?

Or is there a better way to create a Git Repository within a folder of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can drop anything from an Explorer window into Git Bash to find out its Windows path, and then you can replace backslashes with forward slashes to use it with git. For example if the windows path is `\\company\dumptruck\repos` you want to create a repo in it with:

```
git init //company/dumptruck/repos/myproject.git
```

All the other Git commands will work just fine with it. You can clone from there, add as a remote name and push to it, pull from it, everything should work as normal.

However, I have not tested the above with "FTP Sites". As you say this doesn't work with those. In that case, try this instead:

1. Create a local Git repo with `git init --bare sanity.git`
2. Copy `sanity.git` to your FTP Site (simple drag and drop I guess)
3. Try to clone from it:

   ```
   git clone ftp://ftp.mydomain.net/public_html/mysite/sanity.git
   ```

You might have to add username and password to the URL when using with Git, for example:

```
    git clone ftp://user:pass@ftp.mydomain.net/public_html/mysite/sanity.git
```

However, even if you can clone, others seem to get 550 error (access denied) when trying to push to a Git repo over FTP: [Git hosting using an FTP-accessible web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389617/git-hosting-using-an-ftp-accessible-web-server)

In that other question the last suggestion seems to be "check the FTP server logs". Maybe it's a server configuration problem, but I doubt I'd be able to help you with that.

Other (pretty desperate / crappy) things I can think of:

1. Map the FTP Site directory to a drive letter, say `X:`. Then you should be able to work with paths like `/x/public_html/mysite/sanity.git`
2. Use git only locally, and instead of pushing to ftp with a simple `git push`, copy the bare repo itself to ftp from time to time, either manually (drag and drop) or in a batch.
3. Try this project: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the path for my FTP Network place to begin with?  Windows is telling me that the path is this:  `ftp://ftp.mydomain.net/public_html/mysite/folder` so how to use this with gitbash and create a `git init` in the `folder`?

Comment: No, It won't allow me to drop any folders from Windows into GitBash for some reason, but I can drop the Network into GitBash, however, when doing a `ls` command after going to the Network location, I get only 2 files:  `Desktop.ini` and `target.lnk`  I should see my entire site files and folders in here shouldn't I?

Comment: Why wouldn't my sites files/folders be in here?  It's in here for Windows Explorer, but not GitBash.  The path is:  `/c/Documents and Settings/username/NetHood/MySite` and that is what comes up after doing a `pwd` command in GitBash, but like I said, when I do a `ls` command, I get only 2 files, `Desktop.ini` and `target.lnk`

Comment: Using 2nd option with FTP `username:password` I get unable to access `RETR response: 550`.  Using 1st approach without username and password, gives me `Fatal unable to access, Timeout was reached` everytime

Comment: If I use just the username, instead of the password, I get `RETR 530`

Comment: Mapped the FTP site now to Drive W, but doing a `cd /w/public_html` tells me that their is no such file or directory.  Dragging the folder into GitBash works, but hitting enter still says, no such file or directory.  I can now see the network Drive as `W:` in `My Computer` also.  But still GitBash doesn't recognize it. arggg!

Comment: Just for the record, it's a bit more than dragging into GitBash and hit enter: it's really dragging into GitBash + enclose in single quotes + hitting enter, as in `cd 'W:\public_html\site'`. But I guess you did that and it didn't work.

Comment: I tried this just now and it worked!  UNBELIEVABLE!  Must've been something wrong somewhere earlier, but now it is working!  You have to use the quotes!  Problem solved!